# How can I use two translations on the same react app with i18next?

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

I am working on an app where the user can select several buttons. Those buttons need to be translated in the user's language. After the selection a text will be printed which needs to be translated to Japanese.

Input: Many languages
Output: Always Japanese

I could not find any good example my for usecase with i18next on the web. Do you have any idea?

Comment: i18next.t(‘key’, { lng: ‘ja’ })

Comment: Thx, this works. Please put as answer so I can mark it you get the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the lng as options too: `i18next.t('key', { lng: 'ja' })`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to overuse i18next.

If you only need to translate the input, use the i18next on the input and hardcode the japonese text.